# Why do we believe that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x_{ij}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have an absolutely convergent series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k=s$. I manage somehow to index all elements of the series along two dimensions, so each element of the series $x_{k}$ is associated with a pair $(i,j)$ and $i,j \in \mathbb N$ through a bijective mapping, so I can refer to it as $x_{i,j}$ now.

It is clear that any rearrangement of the series absolutely converges to $s$. But why can we claim that (at least my book does so) $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x_{i,j}$.

Expression $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x_{i,j}$ is not just a rearrangement (is not it?), it is a series (over $i$) of an infinite number of series (each over $j$). In a sense it is a series of limits of many sequences of partial sums. Why should we believe that it converges to the same $s$. Am I lacking knowledge of a theorem here?

Comment: Have you seen the proof that the set of rational numbers $Q$ is countable?

Comment: Side note: $x_{ij}$ is a bit misleading in the sense that it looks like the index is a product. I would write $x_{i,j}$.

Comment: @jameselmore yes, you go over an infinite matrix one diagonal after another and thereby provide a method to map all $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb N$. How does it relate hear?

Comment: @Regret OK, edited it.

Comment: perhaps you are lacking knowledge of the theorem that states that an absolutely convergent series can be rearranged in any way, and parenthesis can be inserted in any way (including wrapping infinitely many elements), and the resulting series will have the same sum.

Comment: @IttayWeiss thanks, but I am aware of this theorem (I refer to it in the OP). I think I just refuse to see $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x_j$ as a "sum of infinite number of elements" (is it a well defined idea?),  $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x_j$ for me is just a notation for the limit of partial sums (very well defined idea). And if in the expressions of the OP you see $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x_{i,j}$ not as a wrapping of infinite many elements (again "wrapping" for me is not a well defined idea), but rather as a limit of partial sums, then the equality is not obvious (at least to me). Am I over thinking it?

Comment: the equality is not obvious. The notation is indeed just a limit (but a limit is just a number), and establishing the equality requires proof. Your question suggests that you may not completely understand the notion of a limit, or that you don't quite understand the proof of the theorem in question.

Comment: @IttayWeiss would you be so kind to hint (probably in the form of an answer) how the proof of the equality in the OP can be achieved using the rearrangement theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Reveillark, this is in fact a particular case of the [**Fubini's theorem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#Fubini.27s_theorem_for_integrable_functions). In this case, however, we need not get bogged down by its general setting which involves product measure things (in our case, product of two counting measures). We have a simpler proof.

Let us introduce four notations

$$ s(m, n) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{i,j},
\quad s(\infty, n) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{i,j},
\quad s(m, \infty) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x_{i,j} $$

and finally

$$ s(\infty, \infty) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k. $$

Here, symbols $s(\infty, n)$ and $s(m, \infty)$ are well-defined since

$$ \forall j, \ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_{i,j}| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k| < \infty, \quad \text{and} \quad \forall i, \ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |x_{i,j}| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k| < \infty. $$

Then we find that

- From the rearrangement theorem, we know that $s(m_j, n_j) \to s(\infty, \infty)$ for any *pair* of indexing sequences $(m_j)$ and $(n_j)$ tending to infinity.
- Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists $m_1 < m_2 < \cdots$ such that for each $n$,
  $$|s(m, n) - s(\infty, n)| < \epsilon \quad \text{whenever} \ m \geq m_n. $$
  Consequently,
  \begin{align*}
  |s(\infty, \infty) - s(\infty, n)|
  &\leq |s(\infty, \infty) - s(m_n, n)| + |s(m_n, n) - s(\infty, n)| \\
  &\leq |s(\infty, \infty) - s(m_n, n)| + \epsilon.
  \end{align*}
  and taking $\limsup$ as $n\to\infty$,
  $$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} |s(\infty, \infty) - s(\infty, n)| \leq \epsilon. $$
  But since $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, this implies that the limsup equals 0. Therefore $s(\infty, n)$ converges to $s(\infty, \infty)$ as desired.
- Similar argument shows that $s(m, \infty)$ converges to $s(\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I am not completely getting why $\forall j, \ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_{i,j}| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k|$

Comment: @SergeyZykov, Can you show that partial sums of the LHS are bounded by the RHS?

Comment: I think I can even show that $s_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left| x_{i,j} \right| = s'_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left| x_k \right|$, indeed, the mapping $k \to (i,j)$ can be arbitrary , but because $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left| x_k \right|$ converges absolutely, we can rearrange $\left| x_k \right|$ such that $s'_n$ includes exactly the same elements as $s_n$ for any $n$, so $s_n=s'_n \forall n$, would you agree?

Comment: @sos404 I am not sure why you brought up $\limsup$ at the end of your argumentation. Indeed, we know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |s(\infty, \infty) - s(m_n, n)| + \epsilon= \epsilon$, so starting from $N$ $|s(\infty, \infty) - s(\infty, n)|< \epsilon + \sigma$, where $\epsilon \text{ and } \sigma$ are arbitrarily small, so $\lim_{n \to \infty}|s(\infty, \infty) - s(\infty, n)| = 0$. Would not it work this way without $\limsup$?

Comment: @SergeyZykov, notice that we are *fixing* $j$ when we consider $\sum_{i=1}^m x_{i,j}$. So the sequence $(x_{i,j})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is, upon rearrangement, a *subsequence* of $(x_k)$.

Comment: @SergeyZykov, Of course your argument will give a valid proof. But the argument becomes unnecessarily complicated since $\sigma$ depends on $\epsilon$. The limsup *trick* allows you to circumvent this technicity. Yes, it's a trick, but I found that it is quite useful in many cases for the reason I explained.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22392/discussion-between-sergey-zykov-and-sos440).

Comment: That's fine, but I think I need some rest. It's 7am here and I have not slept all the night…

Answer (score 1):

No, its not a rearrangement in the conventional sense. We need some additional definitions and theorems to interpret and prove this.

A double sequence is a function whose domain is the set $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. We denote the image of the pair $(i,j)$ by $x_{i,j}$.

We say that $\displaystyle \lim_{i,j \to \infty}x_{i,j}=L$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $i>N$ and $j>N$ implies $|x_{i,j}-L|<\varepsilon$. This is called a double limit.

A double sequence induces a sequence $a_j=\displaystyle\lim_{i \to \infty} x_{i,j}$. As such, this sequence may have some limit. It is natural to wonder whether:

$$\lim_{i,j \to \infty}x_{i,j}=\lim_{j \to \infty} \left ( \lim_{i \to \infty} x_{ij} \right )=\lim_{i \to \infty} \left ( \lim_{j \to \infty} x_{i,j} \right )$$

If we know that the sequence has double limit $L$ and that, for each fixed $i$, $\displaystyle \lim_{j \to \infty}x_{i,j}$ exists, then $\displaystyle \lim_{i \to \infty} \left ( \lim_{j \to \infty} x_{i,j} \right )$

Given a double sequence $x_{mn}$, we can define a new sequence by: $$s(p,q)=\sum_{m=1}^p\sum_{n=1}^qx_{m,n}$$

This is called a double series.

Another definition: Given a double sequences $x_{i,j}$ and a bijective mapping $g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, define a sequence by:

$$G(n)=x_{g(n)}$$

The function $g$ is called a rearragnment of the double sequence $x_{i,j}$ into the sequence {$G$}.

We finally have the following result:

Theorem: Let $\sum x_{m,n}$ be a given double series and $g$ a rearrangement into the sequence $G$. Then:

a) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty G(n)$ converges absolutely if and only if $\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty x_{nm}$ converges absolutely.

If, addiotionally, $\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty x_{nm}$ converges absolutely with sum $S$ we have that:

b) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty G(n)=S$

c) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{n,m}$ and $\sum_{m=1}^\infty x_{n,m}$ are both absolutely convergent.

d) If $A_m=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{n,m}$ and $B_n=\sum_{m=1}^\infty x_{n,m}$ then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ and $\sum_{m=1}^\infty B_m$ are both absolutely convergent with sum $S$. This is: $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left ( \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_{n,m} \right )=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left ( \sum_{m=1}^\infty x_{n,m} \right )
=\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty x_{nm}=S$$

For the proof of this result (its rather long so typing it up would be begging for me to mess up the indices), and some other concerning sufficient conditions for the convergence of the double series, see Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*

Comment: Could somebody explain here, why the answer was downgraded?

Comment: so you are saying that the proof of the equality of the OP does not actually have much to do with the theorem about rearrangements (as Ittay Weiss suggested).

Comment: I second that. Could the downvoter explain him/herself? I provided the necesarry definition to understand what I was talking about and wrote down the theorem which answered the OP's question.

Comment: @SergeyZykov There might be a way to use that theorem, but its not immediately apparent to me. Plus, double series is a useful topic which is left out of many Analysis books, while books in other areas assume the reader is familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, when you have absolute convergence you can do whatever crazy rearrangement you want, including spreading the terms of one infinite sum across multiple infinite sums and so forth. Here's a perspective on why that fact boils down to the more basic fact about rearrangements that you seem to be familiar with.

Start out with $\{ x_j \}_{j=1}^\infty$, a sequence which is absolutely summable. Identify this sequence with part of a double sequence by defining $y_{1,j}=x_j$. Then you extend $y$ into a double sequence by defining $y_{i,j}=0$ for $i=2,3,\dots$ and all $j$. Then I claim that

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty y_{i,j}.$$

This is because the sequence $z_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^\infty y_{i,j}$ is identically equal to $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n = \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j$. On the other hand $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^\infty y_{i,j}$ by the definition of the right side.

Now that you've done that, you can get your result by rearranging $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty y_{i,j}$.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it seems to me that you proved the equality only for a very special case (a lot of $0$s in the double sequence). Could you please also specify what you meant by "Now that you've done that, you can get your result by rearranging..." (why we at all are allowed to rearrange it without changing the double series?).

Comment: @SergeyZykov The rearrangement part is a standard (but nontrivial) theorem from basic real analysis.